# My Visual Studio have a trouble

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I don't know what happened with my Visual Studio. What is it? How I can fix it? Problem like that I have just in Visual studio. Other programs working and rendering correct.
If I'll scroll document - VS refreshing and working correct 1 minute, and after happening the same.

Using VS 2010 SP1.

[image]

Comment: reinstall :)   ............................

Comment: Re installed VS, re installed graphical drivers, change monitors, and without result.

Comment: graphic card ? Maby this helps!

Comment: Just get a new one, it could be your graphic card not doing it nay more

Comment: buy any used one it doesnt coast much ) good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I unchecked this option, and right now working perfect!

[image]